# How to modify the existing stl find function in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

Given that I have a data structure,

```
struct data{
int val;
};
struct data A[LEN]; // LEN: some length.

// the below operator would be used in sorting.
bool operator < (struct data &a1, struct data &a2){
return a1.val < a2.val;
}

int main(){
// fill up A.
sort(A, A+LEN); // sort up A

/*Now I want something like this to happen ..
x = find(A, A+LEN, value); -> return the index such that A[index].val = value,
find is the stl find function .. 
*/
}
```

How do you do that ?
And for any stl function how do you get to know which operators to override so that it works in the given condition ?

Comment: You look into [binary search algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) (for example)...

Comment: I actually want to modify the code so as it works with the stl find function. :)

Comment: That's not clear.  Your question title is "how to write your own find function".  But now you are asking how to use the STL find function?

Comment: edited now.. but see the comment in the main.

Comment: Your edit didn't help anything. Are you asking how to write your own `find`, or are you asking how to *use* the one C++ already provides? Edit your question so that it's clear. Adding just one word to the title is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to make [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) work for your array of structure, you need to define `operator==` for struct data:

```
struct data
{
   data(int value=0) : val(value) {}
   int val;
};

bool operator==(const data& l, const data& r) { return l.val == r.val;}

auto x = find(A, A+LEN, value);
```

OR

```
auto x = find(A, A+LEN, data(value));
```

To get index of value in A, use [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

```
std::distance(A, x);
```

Note:
   For more sufficent search with sorted container, use [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), [std::uppper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound), [std::binary_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) instead.

```
auto lower = std::lower_bound(A, A+LEN, data(3));
auto upper = std::upper_bound(A, A+LEN, data(3));
```

Your `operator<` function signature better be like:

```
bool operator < (const data &a1, const data &a2)
//               ^^^^^           ^^^^^
```

Comment: what will be the data type for x ?

Comment: it will be `data*` for x

Comment: maybe it would be meaningful if we return the index of the matched element. Because returning the matched element (actually which we are searching for doesnot make much sense.).

Comment: `distance(A, x)` should give you the index

Comment: Thanks :) one more thing is there a generic way to find out what operators you need to override ?

Comment: Normally `operator<` and `operator==` for STL algorithms. Also compiler message is very intuitive. You could also get a good STL book to learn it through out. :)

Answer (score 3):

The modifications needed to find elements in such a case are pretty minimal. First, you want to make your `operator<` take its arguments as `const` references (technically not necessary for the current exercise, but something you want to do in general):

```
bool operator < (data const &a1, data const &a2){
    return a1.val < a2.val;
}
```

Then (the part that really matters specifically for `std::find`) you also need to define an `operator==`:

```
bool operator==(data const &a, data const &b) { 
    return a.val == b.val;
}
```

Note, however, that you *don't* have to define this if you use a binary search instead:

```
auto pos = std::lower_bound(data, data+LEN, some_value);
```

This will just use the `operator<` that you'd already defined. If the items are already sorted anyway, this will usually be preferable (generally quite a bit faster unless LEN is quite small).